# How to make meta tags dynamic depending on the language on the site in React APP? [React Helmet + i18next]

Tags: reactjs, seo, react-i18next, react-helmet

I am developing website with the use of React App (Create React App), react-i18next, React-Helmet. I tested my website on https://freetools.seobility.net/ and it told me that I don't have meta tags for title and description, however, I do have them. I can see these tags in browser, but the seoBot - couldn't. What about other search engine bots?

[image]

This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This part of my JSON file:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "title": "Frequently asked questions",
    "description": "Find answers to frequently asked questions",
  }
}
```

This the code:

```
const [translation] = useTranslation("assortment");

 return (
        <div className={styles.page}>
            <MetaTags
                title={translation('meta.title')}
                description={translation('meta.description')}
            />
)


//<MetaTags> file

return (
       <Helmet>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <title>{title}</title>
            <meta name="description" content={description}/>
            {noIndex && <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />}
        </Helmet>
    );
```

Should I be worried that Googlebot or other search engines bot wouldn't fully load my page and would see my meta tags? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the right crawling mode, to ensure Seobility SEO Checker has JavaScript execution enabled.

Here you find the right setting:

[image: SEO Check Crawling mode]

If you want to make sure that Google and other bots do not have problems rendering your page with JavaScript, think about server side pre rendering for bots.

Comment: Oh... I need to expand "More options"... My bad. Thank you for the help!